# Getting an attribute value from an XML node in Swift

Tags: swift, xml, nsxmlnode

I am trying to get the value of an attribute in an XML Node in swift.  The following is a code example.  I don't see any way of getting the value as no properties or methods seem to allow for this.

```
for word in dictionary.words {
    let xpath = "/strongsdictionary/entries/entry[greek[@unicode='" + word.word + "']]/pronunciation"
    do {
        let xmlnode = try document?.nodes(forXPath: xpath )
        // Need to get value of attribute named 'strongs' from the node here.
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Error finding xpath path.")
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for macOS or iOS?

Comment: This is for macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlnode` is an array of `XMLNode`. Iterate the array of nodes. If your xpath returns elements, then cast each node to an `XMLElement`. From the element you can get the its attributes.

```
let xmlnodes = try document?.nodes(forXPath: xpath)
for node in xmlnodes {
    if let element = node as? XMLElement { 
        if let strongsAttr = element.attribute(forName: "strongs") {
            if let strongs = strongsAttr.stringValue {
                // do something with strongs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can combine the three `if let` into one but the above is easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your an ace.  That did the trick.  It was not that obvious to me from reading the scetchy documentation.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept an answer that properly answers your question. Click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute is just another node. Change your XPath expression to find it:

```
let xpath = "/strongsdictionary/entries/entry[greek[@unicode='" + word.word + "']]/pronunciation/@strongs"
```

The `.nodes` method returns a list of nodes. Make sure the list is not nil and has one node:

```
    // Get value of attribute named 'strongs'
    if let xmlnode = try document?.nodes(forXPath: xpath ), xmlnode.count == 1 {
        print(xmlnode[0].objectValue)
    }
```

Comment: I could find it that way but I couldn't figure out how to get the value out of it.  Thanks for the help.